# Xdebug CLI in Docker

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I read a lot of posts on GitHub and StackOverflow and I didn't find an answer.

I have Docker container with PHP 7.4 and Xdebug 3. The IDE is PhpStorm. **When I use Xdebug in browser, Xdebug works fine**. But when I use PHP CLI in container, Xdebug doesn't work.

xdebug.ini:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1

xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

I connect with bash from the container: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash`
and run for example: `bin/console my:command` (Symfony). No results, when I add to the config `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` and I can see the warning:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

It looks like the container can't connect with my host system where is PhpStorm with open 9003 port. But when use the same config on webserver it works...

```
root@31aab3e484e1:/var/www/symfony# php -v
PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2020 08:31:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

Where is my mistake? It's php config or maybe PhpStorm?

Comment: When I added to xdebug.ini: `xdebug.client_host = 172.17.0.1` and `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` and ran `export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localhost"` but I don't use Windows/MacOs so I can use `host.docker.internal` like client_host. The IP doesn't seem like good idea (docker and change this IP?). Next question - Why it works on web server in browser??

Comment: 1) There are no other options on linux but to use the IP instead of `host.docker.internal`. 2) Web debugging passes additional `$_SERVER` parameters that aren't available during CLI debugging. Apparently, XDebug detects the correct host to connect to using the parameters from `$_SERVER`. You can check this in xdebug.log

Comment: You CAN use `host.docker.internal` even on Linux now .. but with a few small extra steps. Check https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-772844305 and other comments there.

Comment: @Dmitrii - Yeah, It makes sense. I see that in`$_SERVER` is a lot of 172.* IPs, probably one is uses to connect my host. @LazyOne - Thanks. I found this post and I saw it, but I use docker 19.03 (Linux Mint 20 install as default), but it's support in 20+. I will update docker and test it. Thanks!

Comment: @LazyOne - Thanks for sharing the link, our team wasn't aware of it. Checked on our ends and it worked indeed. 

Comment: I know this is a bit late, could you provide the full command you are using exactly to run the script with the added parameters `xdebug.start_with_request = yes`

Comment: @LaminSanneh This is a question for me? How a command? Symfony? I run only `bin/console app:sth` and it works.

Comment: I think @LaminSanneh thought you're adding the params into the `php` command itself like `php -d xdebug.start_with_request=yes bin/console ...`, but OP said he added that to the php.ini config

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'm using this stack in docker https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp/ and when i run php artisan list I'm getting `Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Add to you project's `docker-compose.yml`

(https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-772844305)

```
services:
  your_php_service_name:
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

In your CLI run
`export XDEBUG_TRIGGER=1 && export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=host.docker.internal"` to start xdebug with the request.

Thanks @LazyOne for his comment to the question with the solution.