# Xdebug not working on WSL inside container

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug

I'm working on Windows (VS Code) with a docker installed in WSL (Ubuntu). All the containers are working correctly (Apache, PHP and MySQL).

In the PHP container (where I have all my code) I have a couple of cron jobs that call every minute a certain endpoints of my app. The breakpoints in these endpoints work well if I access through the web browser, but they don't stop in the cron job (I can also make a curl call inside the PHP container and they won't stop either). These endpoints write a log so I can tell they are being called.

My `xdebug.ini` config and `launch.json` config so far:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port = "9000"
xdebug.idekey = "VSCODE"
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.log_level = 0
```

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/MinAdmin": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a Symphony app, but it also happens in a Drupal app when calling a drush command.

Comment: 1) It's quite common these days to have separate php.ini (as well as xdebug.ini) used by CLI and web server. I suggest you call `xdebug_info();` in CLI (where it does not work) and see if your Xdebug settings are actually applied. Can also compare that with the same captured via browser. 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it has to say. 3) Side note: `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` is from Xdebug v2 and does noting in v3 -- https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_autostart

Comment: P.S. I would also suggest you stick to the new default port `9003` -- to avoid any confusions with php-fpm (that uses TCP 9000 by default as well) -- it was changes for a reason so it makes sense to use new one.

Comment: You sir are correct. I found your answer after you mentioned about the cli/web server differences. The solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322475/xdebug-cli-in-docker#comment117278210_66322475

I tried with the 9000 port and still was working, but I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"hostname": "localhost",` to lunch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "hostname": "localhost", 
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/MinAdmin": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0"
        }
    ]
}
```